# Check whether library is included C++

Tags: c++

I have a function that requires different libraries depending on the values inserted into it, and to prevent different error messages in the log, i want to check if the library needed is included and if not to print an error message more specific than the standard ones.

Is there anyway of checking whether a library is included or not? Something like:

```
   if(#include <iostream>)
     {
        //do this
        }
```

***EDIT:***

Some more details.... i need to check for the libraries in order to know if i can use certain variable types into my code for example to know if i can use type string or if i should use type char[] instead (if the cstring library is used)

Comment: In `#include <iostream>` you are only including headers. If you don't link to the proper libraries at compilation time you'll still get *standard* errors.

Comment: that is an example of what the if is supposed to do..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check if a specific header or macro definition for a given library is defined.

For example:

```
#ifdef BOOST_BUILD
  #include "somebooststuff.h"
  using namespace boost;
#else
  #include "somestdstuff.h"
  using namespace std;
#endif
```

where `BOOST_BUILD` is boost version defined in makefile.

Now, if you want to check if for example header for `std::string` is included, you can open this header and determine what definitions it contains. For example on my machine header for

```
#include <string>
```

contains:

```
//
// ISO C++ 14882: 21  Strings library
//

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_STRING
#define _GLIBCXX_STRING 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <bits/stringfwd.h>
#include <bits/char_traits.h>  // NB: In turn includes stl_algobase.h
#include <bits/allocator.h>
//...
```

so I can check if `std::string` has been defined using:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_STRING
  //do this
#else
  // do this
#endif
```

Comment: not exactly what i wanted... but i can modify this in order to meet my expectations... thank you for your help

Comment: just to be sure...can i use this to check typenames?

Comment: do you need to check for std:: string?

Comment: std:: string ... std::char .. and some other types related to them

Comment: so basically i can check for a header existence by checking for defined statements specific to that header?

Comment: exactly, there is no magic, something specific was defined, something specific is present

Answer (score 3):

If you've got control of the header file in question then you can do some pre-processor magic to do this.

Assuming you've got a header file called **Foo.h** add a:

```
#define FOO_INCLUDED
```

into it.

Then, in the file that you wish to do the check add this:

```
#ifdef FOO_INCLUDED
  #define FOO_WAS_INCLUDED true
#else
  #define FOO_WAS_INCLUDED false
#endif
```

Now you can write:

```
if(FOO_WAS_INCLUDED)
{
  // Do this
}
```

It's not pretty, and you'll get some stern looks, but it'll work!

Comment: Maybe emphasize that FOO_WAS_INCLUDED is a documented feature, and that the include guard itself should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

No, in C++ there is no such construct, which seems borrowed from PHP.

One way to do something related is to statically configure your program with `#define` macros, many GNU and Linux program also come with a `config.h` header.

Small example:

```
g++ -DHAS_IOSTREAM=1

....

#ifdef HAS_IOSTREAM
#endif

if (HAS_IOSTREAM) {....}
```

The convention is to define such macro with a value not equal to zero, or to not define it, so the macro works in all those forms in a relatively idiot-proof manner:

```
if (HAS_IOSTREAM) ....
#if HAS_IOSTREAM ....
#ifdef HAS_IOSTREAM ....
#if HAS_IOSTREAM && SOMETHING_ELSE ....
```

In any case, this configuration is something you usually have to find out *before* compilation.

Also note that you shouldn't rely on include guards. I never discovered any explicit mention of this, but include guards are implementation details to the headers themselves. I've seem them changing, I change them regularly when renaming files.

Comment: but is there any way of finding out if i can use certain syntax without throwing errors?

Comment: @SpiderLinked: No, this is the job of the compiler. And if the compiler's job is to detect syntax errors and to terminate compilation in case thereof, there is no way to enter runtime and execute such checks for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the precense of preprocessor symbols.
As nearly every header file (should) have a header guard you could write e.g:

```
#ifdef Foo_h__
void onlyAvailableIfFooIncluded();
#endif
```

Bigger libraries also often defines some file indepent symbols which are available if you include any header of that library.

Comment: Still, you are only checking if the header is included, not if the library is linked. These types of checks are performed at compile time, and cannot be "depending on the values inserted" in a function.

Comment: But I dont think thats what the OP actually wants considering his snippet and this quote from him: `i want to check if the library needed is included ` .

Comment: They are implementation details you should not rely on.